# Loading icon or progress bar while Curl loads json in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have been searching for something like this, but am unable to find a good solution. I have a page that has 3 tables. Each table uses CURL to pull json info and fill the tables, one by one. Each table is located in a different php file on the index.php page. The page loads in order of the files, and sometimes can take a while depending on the amount of data it is pulling....I would like to put a loading image or if possible a progress bar over the top of each table while/until they load fully...The only solutions I have been successful with is using JavaScript and a loading image for the whole page....I need each section separate....Here's an example of my structure.

```
<?php // index.php
include 'table_1.php'; // loads json into table
include 'table_2.php'; // loads json into table
include 'table_3.php'; // loads json into table
?>
```

Comment: you'd have to do it via separate ajax requests rather than server-side via cURL I think. If that's not possible (e.g. due to CORS or other restrictions) you might need an ajax request to your server, and then a cURL request to the JSON file. But you need something which happens dynamically on the page to add/remove your "loading" indicator when the content arrives. You can't achieve that server-side using PHP - all you can do is send the finished, static page to the client.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this without using javascript but I wouldn't recommend them as they will negatively impact the user experience.

The ideal setup is that you setup 3 ajax requests that run on page load that hits a new endpoint that just returns the views for these tables. You set the contents of #table_1 to a spinner by default.

Here's an example, provided you have jQuery available:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("table_1.php", function(data) {
       $("#table_1").html(data); 
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="table_1">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just load all the tables at the same time once they're all completely loaded? Can you point me to a full example? Appreciate it

Comment: This is all the jQuery code you need to achieve the desired result.

Comment: So I should create an element on my index.php page with the id "table_1" and fill it with a loading animation, and that should show until "table_1.php" is fully loaded...and the same for the others?

Comment: Yes. I've attached a html example

Answer (score 0):

Delete table scripts includes of index.php.
Then return any predermined value from end of each table_1 scripts as   **table_n_end** and in Javascript code, compare these values.
Example :
table_1.php

```
<?php
//... 

//At the end return an predetermined value as
echo "table_1_end";
```

JS loading with index.php

```
//call to Ajax to load table_1.php
    //put a loading image
    if (res1 =="table_1_end") then
        //call to Ajax to load table_2.php
           //put a loading image
           if (res2 =="table_2_end") then 
                //call to Ajax to load table_3.php
                    //put a loading image
                    if (res3 =="table_3_end") then          
                       //Sucess  
                    //end if table_3
                // end Ajax for load table_3  
            // end if table_2  
        //end Ajax for load table_2  
    // end if table_1   
// end Ajax for load table_1
```

Be carefull with *"Callback Hell"*. But any best method is to use **Promises** in Javascript.

Comment: Interesting, but I wish I could understand this a little better...Not very familiar with AJAX functions yet. Any other examples of this implementation? The "echo "table_1_end"; part is a little confusing

Comment: @stoggafu , this is a predetermined value used as a flag indicating script finalization. This value is compared in JS code (for avoid errors) and so on with the other inner Ajax calls.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding this...do I need url's etc in there? I don't see how this is working..

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (res1 =="table_1_end") then
        url: 'test1.php';
           //put a loading image
// end Ajax for load table_1  
</script>

Comment: See the Jquery Ajax call example send by Harlan Wilton.